# How to allow the function to be executed every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have this code where I want to enable the `amurFunc()` to be executed every 5 seconds.

The execution is a listener that listens if the user clicked on the div. He can actually click it every 5 seconds. Can you help me figure out where did I do wrong.

The code:

```
<div id=amur>

</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("amur").addEventListener('click', amurFunc());
    function amurFunc() {
            var funcTimer = 0;
            while (funcTimer == 0) {
                window.open('http://google.com','_blank');
                funcTimer = 5;
                while (funcTimer > 0) {
                    setInterval(
                        function () {
                            funcTimer--;
                        }, 1000;
                    );
                }
            }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you starting multiple `setInterval()` within a while loop?

Comment: @jfriend00 to decrement funcTimer every second till it reach 0;

Comment: You only want to start ONE interval.  It will then run itself every second.  When your count gets to zero, then you call `clearInterval()`.

Comment: But i want when the `funcTimer` reachs zero the external loop to start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div id="amur" style="background-color:red">
 <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

```
var el = document.getElementById('amur');

el.addEventListener('click',amurFunc);


var clicked = 0;
var d = new Date();
var s = d.getTime();
//console.log(s);


function amurFunc(){
    if(clicked==0){
        window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
        clicked++;
    }else{
        var clickedDate =  new Date();
        var clickedSecond = clickedDate.getTime();
        //console.log(clickedSecond-s);
        if((clickedSecond-s)>=5000){
            window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
            s = clickedSecond;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @Bill Hicks - This is a needlessly complex for the task at hand. See my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to use a flag which gets reset every 5 secs. See below:

```
//initially allowed to be clicked
var flag = true;

document.getElementById('amur').onclick = function(){
  if (flag) {
    window.open('http://google.com','_blank');
    //disable click
    flag = false;
    //after 5 secs, click will be enabled again
    setTimeout(function(){
      flag=true;
    },5000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will start `amurFunc()` every 5 sec

```
setInterval(function() {
    amurFunc();
} ,5000)
```

but what do you want to do every 5 sec?

do you want to open page every 5 sec?

why you want to start it on click?

to open page ater 5 sec try this

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
}, 5000);
```

### UPDATE

here is button

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="">
```

here is javascript

```
function Before5Seconds(idName) {
    var btn = document.getElementById(idName);
    btn.value = "Click to start wait 5 sec";
    btn.onclick = function() {
        this.value = "waiting ...";
        setTimeout(function() {
            After5Seconds(idName);
        }, 5000);
    };
}

function After5Seconds(idName) {
    var btn = document.getElementById(idName);
    btn.value = "Click to Go";
    btn.onclick = function() {
        window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
        Before5Seconds(id);
    };

}

Before5Seconds('btn');
```

Comment: This worked fine, but opens google every 5 seconds. When the user clicks on the div i want google to be opened, but he wont be able to open google in the next 5 seconds if he clicks again. It's an algorithm I am working on.

Comment: Here google is used as it was the first page that came to my mind. That's irrelevant.

Comment: @BillHicks so use `setTimeout` to start after 5 sec - my answer is updated.

Comment: You clearly did not understand... I open the .html file, I click on the div, google opens, if I click again it wont open, but if I click again after 5 seconds it will open, and so on. This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: @BillHicks, i got it. It like for showing Ad, you click first time to se Ad next 5 sec then second click goes to required site - i'm updated my answer